# How to alter a hidden field within a TestCase in Laravel 5?

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have the following *Test* in which I'm needing to *alter* the value of a hidden input field, before submitting.

> How can I alter the *hidden* `_token` field before submitting?

```
public function it_fails_to_submit_aun_invalid_token_post()
{
    // Given I am a not authenticated user (guest)

    // And I visit the homepage

    $this->visit('/auth/login');

    // And I fill the login form
    $this->type('test@example.org', 'email')
         ->type('password', 'password');

    // TODO: HERE Change the _token field value to simulate invalidation/tampering
    // Would be something similar to:
    // $this->type('INVALID TOKEN', '_token');
    // But this doesn't work because of (apparently) the DOM lib limitations inherited by TestCase

    $this->click('Login');

    // Then I should see an invalid token message
    $this->see('please submit your form again');
}
```

The full test code on the [github project is here](https://github.com/alariva/timegrid/blob/development/tests/unit/WelcomeControllerTest.php#L78)

There is a [similar discussion on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-to-this-type-in-a-hidden-input?page=1#reply-120377) which seem not to solve this problem yet.

Comment: Couldn't you use the `call()` method for this test? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#custom-http-requests

Comment: @craig_h, I've tried this approach with no success either. This is probably also something wrong here, as It should be working as far as I know. Here the output. http://kopy.io/d2cll

Comment: I think the best way to look at it is Laravel has already tested CSRF. Is there a need to test it in your form itself? Yes ok test your own custom validation..

Comment: @Lee I understand there is no need to test CSRF function. But I'm not testing that either. I'm trying to test a custom view returned when catching the **TokenMismatchException** [as you can see here](https://github.com/alariva/timegrid/blob/development/app/Exceptions/Handler.php#L49)

Comment: A token mismatch is the same thing. An expired session for that token. Again Laravel already has tests in place for it.

Comment: I found what I needed among Laravel tests. But again, what I'm testing is not the token validation by itself, but the *view* I should get upon Exception is raised. Thanks for the hint @Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you've now found a solution for making your test work. I did give this a little more thought yesterday, and I think the overall issue with trying to change the value of a hidden field is that a user cannot realistically change that value, so it doesn't make much sense to try to simulate it. I think in your case, using `session()->regenerateToken();` as you have makes the most sense.

I did, however, have a little play with the `call()` method after looking at your failed test and have come up with a different approach for running a similar test:

```
$this->call('POST', 'auth/login', [
        'email' => 'test@example.org',
        'password' => 'password',
        '_token' => 'foo'
    ]);

// Get the localhost so we can check the redirect
$localhost = 'http://'.request()->server('HTTP_HOST');

$this->assertRedirectedTo("{$localhost}/auth/login");
$this->assertSessionHasErrors(['token_mismatch' => 'please submit your form again']);
```

Here, I made a `post` request using the `call()` method with the relevant fields filled out. Then Laravel provides `assertRedirectedTo()` and `assertSessionHasErrors()` methods, which simply test that you are being redirected to the correct location and that your error message is in the session (I redirected back using Laravels `withErrors()`).

Incidentally, if you wanted to check that the error message was actually displayed, (rather than just in the session) you could do something like:

```
$this->visit("/auth/login")
            ->see('Have you been away? Please try submitting the form again');
```

To simulate the redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I may enhance my test with your suggestions. One thing, the user can actually tamper the token (eg. Google Chrome inspect among many other ways), and the token /session may expire. So it is still a test I want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for writing the test by checking Laravel framework's tests upon @Lee 's suggestion.

I added `session()->regenerateToken();` to simulate an invalid token.

Still, this does not answer how to alter the actual hidden field, but it is no longer required as for this particular need.

```
/**
* Regresion for https://github.com/alariva/timegrid/issues/39
* @test
*/
public function it_fails_to_submit_an_invalid_token_post()
{
    // Given I am a not authenticated user (guest)

    // And I visit the homepage
    $this->visit('/auth/login');

    // And I fill the login form
    $this->type('test@example.org', 'email')
         ->type('password', 'password');

    // And my session expired so as a token was invalidated 
    session()->regenerateToken();

    // And I submit the form        
    $this->press('Login');

    // Then I should see a message asking for resubmit
    $this->see('please submit your form again');
}
```